# Null data parsing data JSON

Tags: ios, json, nsjsonserialization

When I view this (the end of a method) on a browser I see the printout of the JSON echo.

JSON echo

```
[{"0":"2222","id":"2222","1":"john","first":"john","2":"true","last":"true"},{"0":"35","id":"35","1":"Griffin","first":"Griffin","2":"Peter","last":"Peter"},{"0":"40","id":"40","1":"cameron","first":"cameron","2":"Peter","last":"Peter"},{"0":"22","id":"22","1":"Sqgger","first":"Sqgger","2":"Peter","last":"Peter"},{"0":"900","id":"900","1":"sayo","first":"sayo","2":"nara","last":"nara"},{"0":"9000","id":"9000","1":"sayaaao","first":"sayaaao","2":"nara","last":"nara"},{"0":"9001","id":"9001","1":"sayaaao","first":"sayaaao","2":"nara","last":"nara"}]


//Perform query
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM User");

    $myJson=array();
    //Parse to array
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $myJson[]=$row;
        //echo $row['first'] . " " . $row['last'];
        //echo "<br />";
    }

    //Close connection
    mysqli_close($con);

    //Encode and send response
    echo json_encode($myJson);
```

But on my iOS app, the data is null when I put it in NSLog (but I see the bytes, but the array shows as 0x0000

```
NSArray* data=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webData options:0 error:&error];
    NSLog(@"name = %@",[data objectAtIndex:0]);//Null
```

Any thoughts? thanks

Comment: Could you post the json string fetched from the server?

Comment: Added it first code line

Comment: does your application crashes with exc_bad_access? If not try printing [[data objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"id"].

Comment: add the code about webData; You put null data to JSON, maybe that.

Comment: No crash... Just null...

Comment: NSLog(@"name = %@",data); What the log?

Comment: Check you webData. Is that null ?